# ASIHTTPRequest Error, Code 2, on actual iPad

Tags: xcode, ipad, timeout, asihttprequest

I have a program that asynchronously downloads 4 files into the Documents folder of an ipad, and this works perfectly on the simulator, but when I use it on an actual ipad it gives me this error:

`Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=2 "The request timed out" UserInfo=0x1c0810 {NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out}`

Is there any way to fix this, or extend the time until time out?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Why not take a moment to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)? Also, remember to accept correct answers by clicking on the checkmark next to the correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

The reason why you are getting better results in the simulator is probably because the simulator uses the built in network card and your Mac's network card is likely stronger than the one in the iPad.

You can use the following code to change the timeout interval. This code will set the timeout to twenty seconds:

`[request setTimeOutSeconds:20]`

According to the [ASIHTTPRequest "How to Use" page](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use), you can tell ASIHTTPRequest to try again N times, like so:

`[request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:2];`

EDIT:

Although it's 2016 and ASIHTTPRequest is long since deprecated, there's another useful bit of information to help diagnose networking issues on iOS devices. Try using the Network Link Conditioner. It ships with iOS and can be downloaded on macOS.

[This article (link)](http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/) from NSHipster has some great information on getting set up.

Answer (score 0):

Cause of this problem may be the following. When we send a `httprequest` and don't received response from server but at this time you send another `httprequest` again and with second request response is received before first request.